# separation of variables: integral of 1/quadratic

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I have a differential equation $${\frac{dx}{dt}}=x[a-(b+c)]-ax^2$$
where a,b and c are positive constants and there is initial condition: $$x(0)=x_0$$
which I need to solve by separation of variables.
So I have:
$$\int {\frac{1}{x[a-(b+c)]-ax^2}}~dx=t+d$$
where d is some constant that I will work out using the initial condition once I have solved the left hand side undefined integral.
I'm pretty sure the integral is fairly easy to work out but I can't remember at all how to do it... I have tried many substitutions and completing the square on the denominator quadratic and it doesn't seem to make it any easier. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do partial fraction decomposition first
$$
\frac 1{x [a - (b+c)] - ax^2} = \frac 1{x (a' - ax)} = \frac Ax + \frac B{a'-ax} = \frac {Aa' - Aax + Bx}{x(a'-ax)}
$$
from which you can find that
$$
Aa' = 1 \implies A = \frac 1{a'} \\
Aa = B \implies B = \frac a{a'}
$$
so
\begin{align}
I &= \int \frac 1{x [a - (b+c)] - ax^2}\ dx = \frac 1{a'} \int \left( \frac 1x + \frac a{a'-ax}\right )\ dx= \\
&= \frac 1{a'} \left[ \ln x - \ln (ax-a')\right]
\end{align}

### PS

$$
a'=a-(b+c)
$$

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense, except how did you get that last integral to be 1/a'[lnx-ln(ax-a')]? Would it not be 1/a'[lnx-ln(a'-ax)]?

Comment: I just changed the order of the denominator
$$
\int \frac a{a'-ax}\ dx = -\int \frac a{ax - a'}\ dx = -\ln (ax-a')
$$[WA](http://bit.ly/19hz4hi)

Answer (score 2):

Simplify the constants in the integrand to calculate $\displaystyle \int \dfrac{1}{x-kx^2}dx$. The we complete square in th demonitator as

$\displaystyle \int \dfrac{1}{x-kx^2}dx=\int \dfrac{dx}{\frac{1}{4k}-(x\sqrt{k}-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{k}} )^2}$

The substitute $u=x\sqrt{k}-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{k}} $ and the integral becomes

$\displaystyle \dfrac{1}{4k}\int\dfrac{du}{\frac{1}{4k}-u^2}$ and it is more easy =)

Answer (score 1):

$$\int {\frac{1}{x[a-(b+c)]-ax^2}}~dx= -\int {\frac{dx}{ax^2 - x(a-b-c)}} = -\int {\frac{dx}{x[ax - (a-b-c)]}}~dx$$

We can write that:

$$\frac{1}{x[ax - (a-b-c)]} = \frac{P}{x} + \frac{Q}{ax - (a- b -c)} = \frac{P[ax - (a-b-c)] + Qx}{x[ax - (a-b-c)] } = $$
$$= \frac{P[ax - (a-b-c)] + Qx}{x[ax - (a-b-c)] } = \frac{x(aP + Q) - P(a-b-c)}{x[ax - (a-b-c)] }$$

We want to equate both numerators, and hence:

$$x(aP + Q) - P(a-b-c) = 1 = 0x + 1$$

We can now form a system of equations, that must be solved with respect to $P$ and $Q$:

$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}aP + Q = 0 \\ -P(a-b-c) = 1\end{array}\right. \Rightarrow \left\{\begin{array}{l}P = -\frac{Q}{a} \\ \frac{Q}{a}(a-b-c) = 1\end{array}\right. \Rightarrow \left\{\begin{array}{l}P = -\frac{1}{a-b-c} \\ Q = \frac{a}{a-b-c}\end{array}\right. $$

At this point you can say that:

$$\int {\frac{1}{x[a-(b+c)]-ax^2}}~dx = \int\frac{P}{x}dx + \int\frac{Q}{ax - (a-b-c)} = P \log\frac{x}{x0} + \int{\frac{\frac{Q}{a}}{x - \frac{a - b - c}{a}}}dx = -\frac{Q}{a} \log\frac{x}{x0} + \frac{Q}{a}\int{\frac{1}{x - \frac{1}{Q}}}dx =$$
$$= -\frac{Q}{a} \log\frac{x}{x0} + \frac{Q}{a}\log\left(\frac{x - \frac{1}{Q}}{x_0 - \frac{1}{Q}}\right) = \frac{Q}{a}\left(\log\left(\frac{x - \frac{1}{Q}}{x}\right)-\log\left(\frac{x_0 - \frac{1}{Q}}{x_0}\right)\right)$$

Let's pose $\log\left(\frac{x_0 - \frac{1}{Q}}{x_0}\right) = R$ and then come back to differential equation:

$$\frac{Q}{a}\left(\log\left(\frac{x - \frac{1}{Q}}{x}\right)-R \right) = t \Rightarrow$$
$$\Rightarrow \log\left(\frac{x - \frac{1}{Q}}{x}\right) = \frac{a}{Q}t + R\Rightarrow \frac{x - \frac{1}{Q}}{x} = e^{\frac{at}{Q}+R} \Rightarrow x\left(1 - e^{\frac{at}{Q}+R}\right) = \frac{1}{Q} \Rightarrow$$

$$x(t) = \frac{1}{Q\left(1 - e^{\frac{at}{Q}+R}\right)}$$

Comment: Your final answer is wrong.

Comment: sorry, I'm slow... I'm finishing what I want to write

Comment: Just to save you some time, I think you lost $ax$ somewhere, so answer should contain $ax$ under the second logarithm, not just $x$.